# Azure Mobile App API throws error 403 after deployment in Azure

Tags: azure-mobile-services

We have a Mobile backend Service API crated and deployed on Azure. This app makes an external http call to an API using httpClient.GetAsync.
The call works well and returns expected result while running locally, but after publishing on Azure it throws 403(Forbidden) error.

Answer (score 0):

[403(Forbidden)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) is a common error.  Please contact the API provider and check whether there are some restrictions of accessing the AP. For example,

1. Only specific IP addresses(whitelist) can access the API.
2. The API need to verify the client certificate.